# How to get/set specific properties of a video texture in pixi.js?

Tags: video, pixi.js

I managed to get a video to play in Pixi using the following line:

```
    this._texture = PIXI.Texture.from(require("Images/video.mp4"));
```

The problem is that I can't find any properties to do things such as pausing it, forwarding/backwarding, adjusting volume, adjusting playing-speed etc.

Neither the PIXI.Texture or PIXI.Sprite seem to have any properties for this. Is this legitimately all the control PIXI gives you or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a tour [through](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Texture.html) [the](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.BaseTexture.html) [docs](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.resources.VideoResource.html), it looks like you should be able to access the [HTMLVideoElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement) that's playing your video via:

```
this._texture.baseTexture.resource.source
```

And then use members it inherits from [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) like `.pause()`, `.fastSeek()`, `.volume`, `.playbackRate`, etc.